# Installing Doctrine 2 With PEAR

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine, doctrine-orm, pear

I'm a noob to PEAR and Doctrine and got into trouble while trying to install doctrine . From Doctrine's website:

> You can install the release through Github, download, PEAR or Composer

Since the 'download' doesn't actually link to anything I tried using PEAR.

In c:\xampp\php\ I ran this line as explained in the website

```
pear install doctrine/DoctrineCommon-2.3.0
```

And it seemed to go well. However - where is the package downloaded to ? I need the files themselves since I need to drag them to my CodeIgniter folder.

From Google, this is Doctrine's download page http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/download which isn't working ...

Comment: Its probably easiest to use github/composer. The site has been somewhat out of date. As reguards to PEAR, it installs itself into a folder defined in php.ini. Usually this is part of the include_paths setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked on Google?

- [Setting up CodeIgniter 2 with Doctrine 2 the right way](http://www.joelverhagen.com/blog/2011/05/setting-up-codeigniter-2-with-doctrine-2-the-right-way/)
- [Integrating Doctrine 2 with CodeIgniter 2](http://wildlyinaccurate.com/integrating-doctrine-2-with-codeigniter-2)

Also, you can find the last Doctrine 2 ORM version [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html).